# PHP - POST array data with Guzzle or oauth2-client

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, oauth2client

I need some help connecting to deviantArt's API for whois.

I am building a Laravel app that needs to connect to deviantArt's API.

I am able to successfully connect to the API using [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite), [The League's OAuth2-Client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client), [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-fields) and cUrl, but only for a whoami request. 
[GET /user/whoami](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/http/v1/20141114/user_whoami/2413749853e66c5812c9beccc0ab3495)

I can make a successful `whois` connect, but only using cUrl.
[POST /user/whois](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/http/v1/20141114/user_whois/307f0c7e0b6b62cbc0203ee42f2a3fea)

```
curl https://www.deviantart.com/api/v1/oauth2/user/whois \
-d "usernames[0]=justgalym" \
-d access_token=Alph4num3r1ct0k3nv4lu3
```

I'd like to stay using as much of the OAuth2-Client plugin as possible, but at this point, I am just looking for something that works.

My best guess is that I am not sending over the `POST` variables correctly.

#### Attempt 1 - Using Guzzle Request

```
$options = [
  'form_params' => [
    'usernames[0]' => 'justgalym',
    'expand' => 'user.profile',
  ],
  "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$this->token->getToken()
];

$request = new Request('POST', $url, $options);
```

#### Attempt 2 - Using Guzzle Request

```
$options = [
  'form_params' => [
    'usernames[]' => 'justgalym',
    'expand' => 'user.profile',
  ],
  "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$this->token->getToken()
];

$request = new Request('POST', $url, $options);
```

#### Attempt 3 - Using Guzzle Request

```
$options = [
  'form_params' => [
    'usernames' => 'justgalym',
    'expand' => 'user.profile',
  ],
  "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$this->token->getToken()
];

$request = new Request('POST', $url, $options);
```

#### Attempt 4 - Using Guzzle Request

```
$options = [
  'form_params' => [
    'usernames' => 
       [0 => 'justgalym'],
    'expand' => 'user.profile',
  ],
  "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$this->token->getToken()
];

$request = new Request('POST', $url, $options);
```

#### Attempt 5 - Using Oauth-client getAuthenticatedRequest

```
$request = $this->provider->
           getAuthenticatedRequest(
               AbstractProvider::METHOD_POST, 
               $url, $this->token,  ['body' => 'usernames[0]=justgalym'
]);
```

#### Attempt ...

and many others

#### Result for all attempts give me the same error.

```
array(
  'error' => 'invalid_request', 
  'error_description' => 'Request field validation failed.', 
  'error_details' => 
    array(
      'usernames' => 'usernames is required'
    ), 
  'status' => 'error'
)
```

Comment: have you tried to do this using like postman to check if the api returns a different error?

Comment: Yes, that is the api error.
https://www.deviantart.com/developers/errors.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having similar issues with attempt 5, getAuthenticatedRequest

Comment: I guess you need to set headers, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40677875/1619968), it worked for me.