# PHP oAuth POST requests

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

Having a little trouble getting my oAuth POST requests to return a workable response. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
    'POST',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events',
    $_SESSION['access_token'],
    ['body' =>
        json_encode([
            'Id' => null,
            'Subject' => 'Test 54575',
            'Start' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T02:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'End' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T04:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'Body' => [
                'ContentType' => 'Text',
                'Content' => 'estruyf'
            ],
            'IsReminderOn' => false
        ])
    ]
);

$response = $provider->getResponse($request);
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Failed to parse JSON response: Syntax error in C:\projects\agentprocal\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php:663 Stack trace: #0 C:\projects\agentprocal\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php(704): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseJson(NULL) #1 C:\projects\agentprocal\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php(643): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\projects\agentprocal\index.php(58): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\projects\agentprocal\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php on line 663
```

I've had no issues with creating tokens, or requesting data. If anybody needs any further information please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks!

(Using "league/oauth2-client": "^1.4")

Comment: I think I found for you a solution, you just dont set up headers. Please check my answer and let me know if it work :) Im curious of that.

Comment: @KarolGasienica I've responded in your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Correct answer at the end

**Problem**

I'm currently looking inside that class `AbstractProvider` and it seems in vendor you have:

```
protected function parseJson($content) {
    $content = json_decode($content, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) { // ! here that problem occurs
        throw new UnexpectedValueException(sprintf(
            "Failed to parse JSON response: %s",
            json_last_error_msg()
        ));
    }
    return $content;
}
```

which throws an exception that says there is some problem with parsing JSON because in another function we have:

```
protected function parseResponse(ResponseInterface $response) {
    $content = (string) $response->getBody();
    $type = $this->getContentType($response);

    if (strpos($type, 'urlencoded') !== false) { // ! here he checks header
        parse_str($content, $parsed);
        return $parsed;
    }

    // Attempt to parse the string as JSON regardless of content type,
    // since some providers use non-standard content types. Only throw an
    // exception if the JSON could not be parsed when it was expected to.

    try {
        return $this->parseJson($content);
    } catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) { // ! here it catch
        if (strpos($type, 'json') !== false) { // ! again he checks header
            throw $e; // ! and here it throw
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
```

**Solution**

> **It looks like you dont set up right headers.**

So it seems if you add in your request something like:

```
$options['header']['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

it should work, because it will just return a string, without trying to `json_decode()` in `protected function parseJson($content)` method.

In your code it will look like this:

```
$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
    'POST',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events',
    $_SESSION['access_token'],
    ['body' =>
        json_encode([
            'Id' => null,
            'Subject' => 'Test 54575',
            'Start' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T02:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'End' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T04:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'Body' => [
                'ContentType' => 'Text',
                'Content' => 'estruyf'
            ],
            'IsReminderOn' => false
        ]),
     'header' => [
         'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // set header
         ],
    ],
);

$response = $provider->getResponse($request);
```

If you want to get a response in **JSON** you should set your headers like:

```
$options['header']['Accept'] = `application/json`;
$options['header']['Content-Type'] = `application/json`;
```

And it would look in your code like:

```
$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
    'POST',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events',
    $_SESSION['access_token'],
    ['body' =>
        json_encode([
            'Id' => null,
            'Subject' => 'Test 54575',
            'Start' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T02:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'End' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T04:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'Body' => [
                'ContentType' => 'Text',
                'Content' => 'estruyf'
            ],
            'IsReminderOn' => false
        ]),
     'header' => [
         'Content-Type' => 'application/json', // set content type as JSON
         'Accept' => 'application/json', // set what you expect in answer
         ],
    ],
);

$response = $provider->getResponse($request);
```

**Update**

After our chat conversation we got a solution. The problem was with a header and correct code is:

```
$body = [
            'Id' => null,
            'Subject' => 'Test 54575',
            'Start' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T02:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'End' => [
                'DateTime' => '2016-11-17T04:00:00',
                'TimeZone' => 'W. Europe Standard Time'
            ],
            'IsReminderOn' => false
        ];

$options['body'] = json_encode($body);
$options['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';

$request = $provider->getAuthenticatedRequest(
    'POST',
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events',
    $_SESSION['access_token'],
    $options
);

$response = $provider->getResponse($request);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. but seem to be getting the exact same error.

Comment: Try set both headers as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like for JSON

Comment: You can also try some `var_dump` in that vendor functions to check why it makes troubles. For example `var_dump ($content);` before `throw`. And write what is in.

Comment: Switched the header types but to no avail, however after inspecting the throw response I received "Write requests (excluding DELETE) must contain the Content-Type header declaration."

Comment: Change for test POST to DELETE

Comment: "The OData request is not supported."

Comment: There must be a way to set headers before sending a request. I will check and respond soon :)

Comment: Try like it: `'headers' => ['content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']` :) Maybe it misses `s`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128475/discussion-between-alex-and-karol-gasienica).

Comment: (Solution found in chat)

Comment: For me the solution was to use `'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and `'body' => http_build_query($postData),`